# Is it possible to do conditional formatting based on calculated measure in Excel?

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have a quick question. Is it possible to do conditional formatting by calculated measure or field in excel as we do in Power bi? I really can't find an option in EXcel?

Comment: Excel has many conditional formatting options. I'm not a Power BI user. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule to format your cells based on a formula which results in a TRUE or FALSE value. This can be done through Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

In my example the text cells are set to highlight the background in Orange if the Value of the Reference Formula is TRUE. You could also move the formula to a cell on the spreadsheet if you prefer.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXYi8.png)

The formula I am using is a basic example, however whatever you are calculating you will probably need to convert it back to TRUE or FALSE to obtain the formatting you desire.

```
=SUM($B1:$B3) > 3
```

Regarding your question of a Calculated Measure or Field you can also reference a single cell in the above Rules as long as the result is TRUE or FALSE.